# Combining two polynomial equations with different degrees in r

Tags: r, non-linear-regression

I have two polynomial regression lines

1. `v=lm(game_rating~poly(votes,2),data=board_games)`
2. `t=lm(game_rating~poly(timeplay,4),data=board_games)`

Now the question is how to combine these two lines into one to get a new regression `game_rating=f(votes,timeplay)`. What can I do to add them together?

I tried to add them using "+" but `r` shows up in error that non-numeric argument to binary operator.

```
vt=lm(game_rating~poly(votes,2),data=board_games)+lm(game_rating~poly(timeplay,4),data=board_games)
```

*Notes: regression line 1 is between `predictor games_rating` and variable `votes` and polynomial with degree 2 is the best line that can make the prediction. Same for line 2.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Help us help you: Provide a [mcve]. In particular, please [edit] your question to include the output of the R command `dput(board_games)`. Additionally, I feel it is a little unclear what you're looking for. Are you wanting to get a new regression with both predictors? Are you wanting to get the sum of the coefficient multiplied by the predictor from each equation?

Comment: Probably `lm(game_rating ~ poly(votes, 2) + poly(timeplay, 4), data=board_games)`?

Answer (score 0):

adding two linear models probably won't get you what you really aim to get from combining both models, what you need is to run one model with both variables.

Assuming I understand what you want to achieve with adding these models,
 Instead of creating a model to predict `Y ~ x`  and  `Y ~ z` in independent models and then adding them, you should run one model :

`Y ~ x + y`

In your specific case:

```
lm(data = board_games, game_rating ~ poly(votes,2) + poly(timeplay,4))
```